# Reflexive Pronouns

Tags: sentence-translation, english-to-latin-translation, translation-explanation

North & Hillard; Ex. 195: the following is to be translated into Latin: "But, since his men had found no water to drink for many hours, they could not be restrained from rushing into the water, even when it was red with the blood of their comrades."

The answer: "...cuius autem milites, cum aqua multas horas carerent, non sibi temperabant (cohiberi poterant) quin in flumen ipso comitum sanguine rubrum proruerent."

Why the dative reflexive-pronoun "sibi", in "non sibi temperabant", when the natural instinct is to deploy accusative "se"; as in "milites se interfecerunt"—"the soldiers killed themselves"?
Similarly, "ipso", referring to their comrades (the blood of whom): firstly, "ipso" is singular; secondly, why not deploy "ipsorum"; or, just "suorum"—"of their own men"?

Answer (score 5):

It's actually quite common that various orders are given with dative, and we say *tibi impera* or *sibi temperabant*.
Latin usually does not use an accusative object in these cases.
One way to think about it is that orders or constraints are given **to** someone and hence expressed with dative.

You are right that *ipso* can't refer to *comitum*; it would have to be *ipsorum*.
Instead, it refers to *sanguine*.
When something doesn't make sense, look for other words that might go together with what puzzles you!
It's quite useful to carefully go through all the words (even implicit ones in some cases) and see what your pronoun or adjective or something can refer to.
Using *ipso* puts emphasis on the blood instead of the comrades, making the water "red with the very blood of their comrades".

Most importantly, there is no unique correct answer to a translation task like this.
There are multiple choices you can make.
You could use *ipsorum* instead of *ipso* or leave the whole word out.
You could use *sui* instead of *cuius milites*.
You could rush into the water with another verb.
The answer key gives you an example translation, not **the** translation.

If you are in doubt, you can ask questions with the original English sentence, your translation and the textbook's translation side by side and ask us to evaluate your translation.
It might turn out that your translation is perfectly valid although very different from the suggested answer, or it might turn out that you are mistaken about something.
If you ask such questions here, please elaborate on what you are worried about as you did here.

Comment: llmavirta  Thanks. There is no concept of "ordering",  here. The thirst-crazed soldiers could not control themselves. There may be a case, therefore, for putting "temperabant" in the passive; but, checking in Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict., "tempero" can mean the controlling of others or self. So, it can be further argued that a feflexive pronoun is unnecessary; giving; non temperabant--they were not controllong/ did not control themselves? Any thoughts?

Comment: llmavirta: Thanks. There is no concept of ordering, here. The thirst-crazed soldiers could not control themselves. It could be argued that "temperabant" should be passive. Checking Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict., "tempero" can mean the restraining of others or self; therefore, it may be argued, further, that a reflexive pronoun is unnecessary, giving: "non temperabant"--they were not controlling/ did not control themselves? Any thoughts?

Comment: The first one disappeared, repeated it; first one returned!

Comment: @tony You need the reflexive *sibi* with *temperabant*. The men were unable to give constraints **to themselves** (= *sibi*). If *temperare* took an accusative object, you could replace *se*+active with passive, but you can't (usually) passivize something that works with datives. Whether you give orders (*imperare*) or constraints (*temperare*), you give them **to** someone with a dative. I'm not aware of *temperare* being used to controlling oneself without *sibi*, but it can well be a matter of my limited knowledge.